# Nginx as a proxy for request, but bypass nginx for response?

Tags: nginx, proxy

I need to setup an NGinx configuration as a proxy for my underlying service but I'd like to know if it's possible to avoid returning the data to NGinx then to the client, but directly to the client.

A picture being more describing :[image: NGinx Proxy]

The main idea here is that NGinx would accept all the requests, but would not process the response, those would be directly transferred back to the client.

But there is one important thing : The client must not see (at least in the url bar) the url of the internal server, only the url of the front NGinx proxy.

Is it possible to implement this in NGinx and if so, how ?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Impossible, think about how the networking would work in this case. You can't just initiate a TCP connection to some browser.

Comment: Thank you Andre. So if I take the example of any CDN, they can't do that, and process the requests AND responses ?

Comment: They have special hardware where one IP maps to MANY backend servers. Amazon and many other server hosters allows you to purchase such IPs.

Comment: I was thinking about Amazon Route 53, and setting a dns entry to point to all my proxies with a health check in place. Do you have a better alternative? I can't find a service that allow me to buy a Load Balancing IP and connect it to my servers (may be outside that service). And if I'm not mistaken, Route 53 will return the IP of one of my proxy, causing issue if it goes down for the user currently using it, right ? (if you are ok, we can continue this discussion in chat)

Comment: I don't have any experience in that area. Sorry.

Comment: You previously said Amazon and many other server allow to purchase such IP. From Amazon, what is the service name/url ? thank you :)

Comment: That's usually called "load balancing" https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

Comment: I was hoping you would not talk about Amazon ELB because they require you to connect to EC2 instances, and I plan to use something else ;) Thank you for your help!

Comment: The `Direct Server Return` mode for load balancers might be relevant. https://www.nginx.com/blog/ip-transparency-direct-server-return-nginx-plus-transparent-proxy/